# Insufficient Permissions to SSH into GCP VM

Tags: ssh, permissions, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

Good day ladies and gents,

I'm having an issue with being able to SSH into a GCP VM due to insufficient permissions. The 'error' is: [awesome picture #1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FgUss.png)

The permissions on my account are: 
[awesome picture #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FGf1w.png)

According to picture #1 and this link (https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/iam) I only need to be an instanceAdmin.v1 as that will give me compute.projects.setCommonInstanceMetadata permissions. However, I still have no luck getting in.

I presume I am missing something very simple. Is there any chance anyone would know a thing or two about this?

-Kieran

Comment: Does `gcloud auth list` match the credentials in your picture?

Answer (score 2):

This [Google documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/managing-instance-access) shows the steps you must do:

> 1. Enable the OS Login feature on your project or on individual instances.
> 2. Grant the necessary IAM roles to yourself, your project members, or your organization members.
> 3. Optionally, complete any of the following steps:
>
>    - Add custom SSH keys to user accounts for yourself, your project member, or organization members. Alternatively, Compute Engine
>        can automatically generate these keys for you when you connect to
>        instances.
>    - Modify user accounts using the Directory API.
>    - Grant instance access to users outside of your organization.
> 4. Connect to instances.
> 5. Review the expected login behaviors.